# How do I add a text variable after a number variable sum in Python 34?

Tags: python, variables, text, floating-point, numbers

```
print("This program calculates information about rectangles/squares.")
length = float(input("The length is "))
width = float(input("The width is "))
unit = input("The unit of measurement is ")
print()
print("The area is ", length * width)
print("The perimeter is ", 2 * length")
```

I need to add the user input for unit to appear at the end of the measurement. For example, if the user inputs cm for the unit of measurement, I want x cm; instead of just x.

Comment: Calculate the result before and use it with string.format. You might also want to check the perimeter formula...

Comment: @ydaetskcoR: And the area formula; the area of a 3 cm x 4 cm rectangle is not 12 cm, it's 12 cm^2…

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just put in another comma:

```
print("The area is ", length * width, unit)
```

The [`print`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#print) function just converts each argument to a string,* and prints them on a line together with a space between each.**

Just like you can use that to print `"The area is "`, you can use it to print whatever's in `unit`; if that's `"cm"`, it'll print `The area is  42 cm`.

(Note that you probably didn't want that space at the end of `"The area is "`, because `print` is already going to add one there.)

In general, once you get beyond trivial cases, it's usually more readable to use string formatting. But for simple cases (while you're learning, for quick&dirty scripts, for exploratory debugging, etc.), `print` with multiple arguments is usually fine.

---

<sub>* A string converted to a string is just itself, which you can already see with `"The area is "`.</sub>

<sub>** Although you can configure the "on a line" and "with a space between" with the keyword arguments `end` and `sep`; see the linked docs.</sub>

Comment: I still get `NameError`. Cm not being defined, something like that.                                                      `length = float(input("The length is "))
width = float(input("The width is "))
unit = input("The unit of measurement is ")
print()
print("The area is ", length * width, unit)
print("The perimeter is ", 2 * length + 2 * width, unit)`

Comment: @SpontaneousCombustion: That's a different problem, so you should create a different question… but I'll bet I know what's wrong. You're trying to write Python 3 code, but you're using Python 2. In Python 2, `input` tries to evaluate the user's input as if it were Python source code; you want `raw_input` instead. Also, you don't want parentheses around your `print` arguments in Python 2.

Comment: @ch3ka: Sure it is. Well, it's missing a period, and you didn't capitalize the first letter (but the OP and I both did), and obviously `cm` is the wrong unit to use for area, but what do you think is wrong with it as a sentence?

Comment: The "it's not an area unit" thing. While syntactically correct, it just makes no sense so say (or print) such a sentence.

Comment: @ch3ka: OK, it _is_ a valid (English) sentence, but it's mathematically silly, agreed.